# what is customizable serialization form?

Tags: java, serialization

I am new to java programming. Can anybody tell me what is customizable serialzation form with an example. what is the diffrence between serialization proxy and customizable serialization?

Comment: Please use the search before posting questions. There are already a lot of anwers out there for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290777/java-custom-serialization. For a general introduction to serialisation see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 2):

First, I should point out that this kind of terminology is a bit "rubbery".  The meaning is liable to vary depending on the context ... and who used it.

The Serialization Proxy Pattern is nicely summarized by this Q&A: [What is the Serialization Proxy Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702357/what-is-the-serialization-proxy-pattern).  From that, we infer that a "serialization proxy" is an object that is serialized instead of the object that you requested to be serialized.  (Read the linked Q&A)

AFAIK, there is no such thing as "customizable serialization form".  You probably misread it somewhere ... or were mislead by some "dodgy English".  The best I can come up with is that Java serialization *is customizable* ... and the Serialization Proxy Pattern is one example of how you can customize it.  For other examples, refer to the Java serialization docs:

- The specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html
- The examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/examples/index.html