# What different between List$SerializationProxy and List in Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, serialization

What different between

```
scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy
```

and

```
scala.collection.immutable.List
```

in Scala 2.11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List$SerializationProxy` is a helper class that is used by `List` to implement the [Serialization Proxy Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702357/what-is-the-serialization-proxy-pattern)

You can see some discussion about this in the source code, [List.scala:415](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L415)

```
// Create a proxy for Java serialization that allows us to avoid mutation
// during deserialization.  This is the Serialization Proxy Pattern.
protected final def writeReplace(): AnyRef = new List.SerializationProxy(this)
```

You do not need to use or interact with `List$SerializationProxy` as a normal user of Scala, it is an implementation detail.